# How can I convert Json into 2D array?

Tags: arrays, json, swift, decode, codable

If I got a Json  like this:

```
{ "i": [ "0", [123]] }
```

Is there any possible way can decode the 2D array above?

```
class ModelA: Codable{
    var i: [String]?
    var temp: [Any] = []

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case i = "i"
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let value = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        temp = try value.decode([Any].self, forKey: .i)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public func printJsonData(){

    let jsonData: Data = """
    {
        "i": [ "0", [123]]
    }
    """.data(using: .utf8)!

    if let model = try? JSONDecoder().decode(ModelA.self, from: jsonData){
        print(model.temp)
    }else{
        print("no data")
    }
}
```

I have tried that an array [Any] works successfully here,
but can't find any method to convert in 2D array.
If someone knows how to solve this problem, or knows this is impossible in Swift4.2, please tell me. Thanks!

Comment: The problem is not that it's a 1D or 2D array, the problem is that your array has different types.

Comment: @regina_fallangi I can decode different Json like {"i": ["123",456]} which included String and Int, but only cant't work if a array inside the array

Comment: That question already has an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48749302/decoding-json-array-of-different-types-in-swift

Comment: @regina_fallangi this seems not answer my question QQ

Comment: If you really don't know the types (if they really are `Any`), and can't change what's sent from the server - you should look at converting your json into dictionaries and arrays - look at `JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: options: )`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know the possible data types for the array value, perhaps you can try using the possible value (in this case `String` and `[Int]`) represented by enum instead of `Any`.

e.g:

```
enum ArrayIntOrString: Decodable {

    case string(String)
    case arrayOfInt([Int])

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

        if let string = try? decoder.singleValueContainer().decode(String.self) {
            self = .string(string)
            return
        }

        if let arrayOfInt = try? decoder.singleValueContainer().decode([Int].self) {
            self = .arrayOfInt(arrayOfInt)
            return
        }

        throw ArrayIntOrStringError.arrayIntOrStringNotFound
    }

    enum ArrayIntOrStringError: Error {
        case arrayIntOrStringNotFound
    }
}
```

And declare it in your model:

```
class ModelA: Decodable {

    var i: [ArrayIntOrString]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case i = "i"
    }   
}
```

usage

```
public func printJsonData() {

    let jsonData: Data = """
    {
        "i": [ "0", [123]]
    }
    """.data(using: .utf8)!

    do {
        let model = try JSONDecoder().decode(ModelA.self, from: jsonData)
        print(model.i)
    } catch let err {
        print("no data \(err)")
    }


}
```

Comment: You can remove `CodingKeys` in this case