# How to decode JSON that has multiple lists that are unnamed in Swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift, struct, codable

I am trying to decode a JSON string but it seems to have multiple lists that do not have any names/keys that I can call with my structs. From what I can tell (with the little knowledge I have) there are two lists inside of this JSON and I only want the second list. I know how to decode normal JSON but figuring out how to call this keyless list/array is perplexing.

I tried to make my struct use 0 or 1, depending on which list I wanted, as the case name but that did not work either. I am really just confused on how to call something that is not named explicitly. Below is my JSON data and code.

Here is a small portion of the JSON:

```
[{
    "page": 1,
    "pages": 1,
    "per_page": "5000",
    "total": 58
  },
  [{
    "indicator": {
        "id": "NY.GDP.MKTP.CD",
        "value": "GDP (current US$)"
    },
    "country": {
        "id": "US",
        "value": "United States"
    },
    "value": "19390604000000",
    "decimal": "0",
    "date": "2017"
  },
  {
    "indicator": {
        "id": "NY.GDP.MKTP.CD",
        "value": "GDP (current US$)"
    },
    "country": {
        "id": "US",
        "value": "United States"
    },
    "value": "18624475000000",
    "decimal": "0",
    "date": "2016"
  }]
 ]
```

Here is my Swift code:

```
    let url = URL(string:"https://api.worldbank.org/countries/USA/indicators/NY.GDP.MKTP.CD?per_page=5000&format=json")!

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data,response, error) in
        if let data = data {
            let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
            let countryData = try? jsonDecoder.decode(CountryData.self, from:data)
            print(countryData?.data)
        }
    }
    task.resume()

    struct CountryData: Codable {
         let data: [Country]
         enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
               case data = ""
         }
         init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
               let valueContainer = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
               self.data = try valueContainer.decode([Country].self, forKey: CodingKeys.data)
         }
   }

    struct Country: Codable {
          let value: String
          let date: String
          let total: String
          enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
                case value = "value"
                case date = "date"
                case total = "total"
          }
          init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
                let valueContainer = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
                self.value = try valueContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: CodingKeys.value)
                self.date = try valueContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: CodingKeys.date)
                self.total = try valueContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: CodingKeys.total)
          }
    }

    extension URL {
          func withQueries(_ queries: [String: String]) -> URL? {
                var components = URLComponents(url: self, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true)
                components?.queryItems = queries.compactMap
                    { URLQueryItem(name: $0.0, value: $0.1) }
                return components?.url
          }
    }
```

I really just want to eventually access the dates and put them into an array for a tableView and be able to access the rest of the JSON data for the following view.

Thank you so much,
Jack

Comment: Those “keyless list” `[item1, item2, ...]` are called JSON *arrays.*

Comment: Is it possible to change the JSON?

Comment: @ChanchalChauhan No, I don’t think so because it’s from an api. I guess I could change it after I get JSON and delete some bits, but I’d rather not do it that way.

Comment: @DamiaanDufaux that question is asking something different. It is not a duplicate. I don’t have an issue with different types, I have an issue with calling a JSON array that has no name.

Comment: @JackWelch Check dávid-pásztor's answer it is an exact answer to your question and an almost exact duplicate of the [answer to the duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48749302/decoding-json-array-of-different-types-in-swift#answer-48765415). JSON arrays do not have to be named, the can occur at the top level. The difficulty in decoding here lies in the fact that it is a polymorph array (an array that contains objects with different types)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You simply need to use `decoder.unkeyedContainer()` when decoding a JSON Array manually. Then you can specify the type of the elements you want to decode one-by-one, which you'll need, since the first and second element of your array are different. If they were the same, you could simply decode it using `JSONDecoder.decode([ArrayElementType].self)`.

```
struct CountryData: Decodable {
    struct Indicator: Decodable {
        let id:String
        let value:String
    }

    struct Country: Decodable {
        let id:String
        let value:String
    }

    let indicator:Indicator
    let country:Country
    let value:String
    let decimal:String
    let date:String
}

struct CountryDataResponse: Decodable {
    let countries:[CountryData]

    struct CountryDataRoot: Decodable {
        let page:Int
        let pages:Int
        let per_page:String
        let total:Int
    }

    init(from decoder:Decoder) throws {
        var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
        try container.decode(CountryDataRoot.self)
        countries = try container.decode([CountryData].self)
    }
}

let countries = try JSONDecoder().decode(CountryDataResponse.self, from: yourJson)
```